# material-ui-pickers cancel actually displays value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

using //https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker
Configured like below.  this.state.start_year_date starts at null.  Works great when user brings up the modal and selects a date and clicks OK.  However, if they bring up modal, and hit cancel, it displays 2019 (!??!?!) after the modal closes.  However since they didn't actually choose 2019, state.start_year_date is not set to 2019, it is still null.  Things go sideways from there.  How can I prevent cancel from doing that?

```
                <DatePicker
                  value={this.state.start_year_date}
                  onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}
                  views={["year"]}
                  disablePast={true}
                  label={"Start year"}
                  onAccept={this.handleStartDateAccept}
                  maxDate={ this.state.end_year_date ? this.state.end_year_date : (new Date().setYear(2099) ) }
                />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the onClose method to either reset the value to the original value or set it to whatever you like.

```
<DatePicker
   value={this.state.start_year_date}
   onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}
   views={["year"]}
   disablePast={true}
   label={"Start year"}
   onAccept={this.handleStartDateAccept}
   maxDate={ this.state.end_year_date ? this.state.end_year_date : (new Date().setYear(2099) ) }
   onClose={ () => this.setState({start_year_date: 2019 }) }
/>
```